# Function append javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn1r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn1\").show()'>Auto</b>");
    $("#btn1").hide();
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn2r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn2\").show()'>My</b>");
    $("#btn2").hide();
  });
  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn3r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn3\").show()'>blue</b>");
    $("#btn3").hide();
  });
  $("#btn4").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn4r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn4\").show()'>is</b>");
    $("#btn4").hide();
  });
});

var a = 'My car is blue';
var b = //append or removed text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>My car is blue</b>
<p></p>

<button id="btn1" value="car" onclick="$(this).val();">car</button>
<button id="btn2" value="My" onclick="$(this).val();">My</button>
<button id="btn3" value="blue" onclick="$(this).val();">blue</button>
<button id="btn4" value="is" onclick="$(this).val();">is</button>
```

I'm creating this game in javascript but I can not write the function that populates the variable `b` to compare `a = b`. I should populate the variable `b` with the order of the buttons I press and also I should remove the text if it is hidden.

Comment: Why are you intermixing inline bindings and logical bindings?  Edit: Also there is no need to lookup the element again in those 4 click handers.  The `this` will reference the btn that was clicked already.

Comment: Suggestion: don't do element creation inside an `append()` function and don't add inline events to html using `onclick`, do it in javascript file, create a separeted function that you can call. It will let your code much more clean and easy to maintain and scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation to add to `b`, with

```
b + " " + $(this).text();
```

When you do the comparison, you should remove the space at the beginning with `b.trim()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn1r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn1\").show()'>Auto</b>");
    $("#btn1").hide();
    b += " " + $(this).text();
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn2r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn2\").show()'>My</b>");
    $("#btn2").hide();
    b +=  " " + $(this).text();
  });
  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn3r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn3\").show()'>blue</b>");
    $("#btn3").hide();
    b += " " + $(this).text();
  });
  $("#btn4").click(function() {
    $("p").append(" <b class='phs' id='btn4r' onclick='$(this).remove();$(\"#btn4\").show()'>is</b>");
    $("#btn4").hide();
    b += " " + $(this).text();
  });
});

var a = 'My car is blue';
var b = '';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>My car is blue</b>
<p></p>

<button id="btn1" value="car" onclick="$(this).val();">car</button>
<button id="btn2" value="My" onclick="$(this).val();">My</button>
<button id="btn3" value="blue" onclick="$(this).val();">blue</button>
<button id="btn4" value="is" onclick="$(this).val();">is</button>
```